# Connecting 25+ bluetooth devices and 3+ displays

Tags: graphics-cards, bluetooth, displays, high-end

I want to set up a special training room in the gym I work for, but being mostly a software guy, hardware is sometimes a mystery to me.

The idea is the following: have 3+ displays showing videos of how should exercises be performed, and have people in the class wearing Bluetooth-enabled heart-rate monitors and show their heart-rates on a separate display.

I was wondering what the best hardware for this would be:

1. I've done a lot of research, and it seems that one computer **can only support up to ~12 Bluetooth devices** connected at once. It seems I could have multiple Bluetooth adapters connected to one computer, but I couldn't find any consensus: could I then connect 12 Bluetooth devices for each USB adapter? I have no OS constraints at this point, but have a preference for MacOS or Linux. Would that work with either?
2. I'd need to connect to ~3 displays to stream the exercise videos. Each display should show 3 separate videos. Since there are many exercises and they could be paired in any way, this means that each screen is going to be playing 3 videos at the time, min. resolution 720p. Assuming that I can't change that, what kind of hardware would I need for something like that? Would I need to add additional external GPUs for instance?

So, these are the only two requirements: OS and even budget (within reason) is not an issue. Any pointers?

Comment: Which "BlueTooth devices" were you thinking of connecting?

Comment: @Alex specifically, we're looking into connecting heart-rate monitors.

Comment: @NinGen ShinRa, do you have a particular brand in mind? There are multiple versions of Bluetooth and they have differing range capabilities. Please click on [edit] when you reply, instead of using Comment; Comment is for folks besides the original poster, whereas when you [edit] the original question, you add useful info everyone should see. Also, please see https://superuser.com/questions/931188/how-many-devices-can-be-hooked-up-to-one-pc-bluetooth-adapter-at-a-time

Comment: Please clarify with [edit]; do you want to have three big screen displays, each streaming one exercise video to the entire room, plus one personal display per user showing heart rate for that user OR each user has four images going on their display; three exercise videos plus their heartrate?